# sql to remove repeating data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have problem with data that I need to filter out to produce a report.

Basically every day we take a file and load it into the system but the file is cumulative file and is basically re imported with the same information plus the new data daily.

This loads into the Database into two tables, a header and detail table.

In the header table I have the key filed of No_, the date it was imported and the month and year the data is for (period) an example would be 'Apr2013'.

The detailed table holds all of the information from the import as you can imagine.

What I'm looking to do is to disregard all of the older data and only look at the most recent import for that month only.

Hopefully someone can help me, if you want me to post any example data or anything then please let me know and I'll add it in.

Thanks in advance!

Phil

Comment: what tool(s) are you using for the export?

Comment: My first thought would be to change your load procedure and only load the new data. Is that not possible?

Comment: @Melanie thats what his question is "What I'm looking to do is to disregard all of the older data and only look at the most recent import for that month only."

Comment: Or is he going to continue to add all the data to the database and his question is how to pull only the new data out in a query?

Comment: good question! phil needs to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot change your process to stop re-importing the same data over and over - especially if the data *is* exactly the same - you could try the following query:

```
WITH MostRecentData AS
(
    SELECT MAX(dateImported) dateImported, month, year
    FROM header
    GROUP BY month, year
)
SELECT ...
FROM detail d
INNER JOIN header h ON h.[key] = d.[key]
INNER JOIN MostRecentData r ON h.month = r.month AND h.year = r.year 
    AND h.dateImported = r.dateImporter
```

This will pull out the latest rows (based on the date imported) for each month and year.

Honestly though I would try to change the import process if possible. It sounds like a lot of wasted space and subsequent processing to pull out the data you want.

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately I can't change the process and we have to continue to add the data in every day. I know it's in efficient but the system and processes have been built around this as crazy as it sounds.

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue though by using the basis of your example and simplifying it somewhat so that is just has:  select * from detail_Table where [ID from the detail table] in (
 select MAX([Detail_Table].[ID]) from [Detail Table] group by [Period of the data])